# How can I generally estimate the relevance of error introduced by a calculation in a program using floating point numbers

Tags: floating-point, precision

I'm currently learning about representation errors more deeply when using floating point numbers. I  understand the fact that some decimal numbers cannot be exactly represented in floating point.

It's unsettling that when I write a program where there are multiple calculations over numbers, the errors can get big enough to cause significant issues.

How can I estimate how big an error can be and whether or not floating point numbers will be problematic enough to use an alternative, given I know what is the equation I'm applying to a set of numbers?

I'm sure there must be literature about how to do that but I haven't found the keywords. Could anyone please share resources that are specific about figuring out how much error will be introduced by your formula and the range of your data?

I tried reading about the topic and working some examples but I could not extract a general equation or method.

Comment: Re “I'm sure there must be literature about how to do that but I haven't found the keywords”: The keywords are [numerical analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_analysis). And there is no general equation or simple method; the numerical errors that result from a sequence of calculations can range from zero to infinity or can produce NaN values (Not a Number). Error estimation is dependent on the specific algorithms and numbers used.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks for your response! "Error estimation is dependent on the specific algorithms and numbers used" I'm happy with having categories of algorithms, i.e a sumatory where I know the exact number of fractional digits of the inputs. That sounds like something on the easy side of the spectrum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its hard to pack 6-months of college [numerical analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_analysis) in a Stack overflow answer, but something for OP to start on.

---

> How can I estimate how big an error can be (?)

Some guidelines:

- What is *error*?  Are we looking for the *absolute* `x - expected_x` or *relative* `(x - expected_x)/expected_x` [error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_error#Formal_definition)?  (Usually its the relative one, unless near 0.0 - or the ULP error)
- First, understand [unit in the last place (ULP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place) for floating point types.
- Converting decimal text to/from floating point types impart about 0.5 ULP error.
- Multiplications/divisions/`sqrt()` tend to impart about 0.5 ULP error.
- Addition/subtraction tend to impart about 0.5 to **[many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catastrophic_cancellation)** ULP error.
- Trig functions tend to impart about a few ULP error.
- Functions like `exp()` can greatly amplify errors: `error_y = error_x * exp(x)`.
- Edge cases near 0.0 and infinity often need special consideration.

> I could not extract a general equation or method.

Oversimplified: [variance formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty#Simplification).

Also review [Errors and residuals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errors_and_residuals).

Comment: These are misleading. `sqrt` might average around ½ ULP error added, but it reduces prior error. Subtraction of numbers close to each other does not add error at all; the result is exact. Prior absolute error is unchanged. Relative error changes only because the result is smaller.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I am certain we agree there is much to error analysis than what can be fully provided in a SO  Q & A.

Comment: @EricPostpischil  Curious you should mention `sqrt` and subtraction:  "Subtraction of numbers close to each other does not add error at all; the result is exact" --> Consider `d = a - b`, and `a, b` in the same power-of-2.  if `a, b` are exact, the error in `d` is 0 - as you mentioned.  Yet if `a, b` have prior ULP error, the ULP error in `d` maybe orders of magnitude greater.  With `y =sqrt(x)`, is somewhat opposite.  If `x` is without error, `y` is likely to have 1/2 ULP error.  If `x` has error `e`, the the error is typically reduced, as you mentioned.

Comment: Perhaps I should emphasize that ULP error is primarily a _relative_ error assessment.